# Quantity Discount

Tags: admin, quantity, pricing

I am trying to add a quantity discount when someone buys more then 1 of my products. For example, the first one is $19, then every additional item added is $6. I do not want to show it as a discount in the cart, I just want the total of the product to be reflection of how many units they are buying.

For example, $19 (1 unit), $25 (2 units), $31 (3 units).

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Tier Prices Feature.

Go To `Catalog > Manage Products`  open any product, go to `Price` section,

than you can see Tier Price , click on `Add Tier` than enter the number of quantity and Price and ave the product.

But it is manual procedure, for each individual quantities you have to set manually price. It will not update the price per each item without entering values in backend.

Also this will display in site to customers that Prices per quantity

[image]